# remove specific fields from tab separated input file

Tags: awk, gawk

input file#1 with tab separated fields:

```
one     two     three   four    five    six     four
one     two     three   four    five    six     four
one     two     three   four    five    six     four
```

case1: from each line, I need to remove all fields containing a string, for example `four` and get still single TAB separated remaining fields.

case2: I need to remove nth columns and leave still one TAB separation for the remaining fields on output, but here I get multiple TABs:

```
$ echo -e "one\ttwo\tthree\tfour\tfive\tsix\tfour\none\ttwo\tthree\tfour\tfive\tsix\tfour\none\ttwo\tthree\tfour\tfive\tsix\tfour"|awk -F"[\t]" '{$3="";$5=""}{print $0}' OFS='\t'
one     two             four            six     four
one     two             four            six     four
one     two             four            six     four
```

I can fix it by sending output via `tr -s '\t'`, but how to modify awk to avoid the `tr` command?

Comment: So you expect `one|two|four|six|four` ?

Comment: sorry, I removed misleading things from the description. I need single TAB separated fieleds on the output.

Comment: Nothing was misleading. By a single pipe I meant a single tab as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pipe output to `sed`, even though `awk` would be a working solution:

```
sed 's/\t*[^\t]*four[^\t]*//g'
```

Alternatively with `awk`:

```
awk -F\\t '{r = ""; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i !~ /four/) r = (r=="" ? "" : r FS) $i; print r}'
```